# ImportError: Environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm going through the basic django tutorial and I'm running the server using python manage.py runserver. And I get this error that I'm not quite understanding how to sort out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 1, in <module>
    from polls.models import Poll
  File "/Users/davidhaddad/Desktop/mysite/polls/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    if DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS not in settings.DATABASES:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

settings.py was visible earlier and I started getting this message after I added some code to register a few app models with admin.

To give some more info: when I do export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings from inside the project directory and then i do python django-admin.py runserver the server doesn't run (nothing is shown).

Comment: Google is your friend.. try "what is an environment variable"...

Comment: updated question with a bit more details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to be able to import the value of `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` when you're in a location that isn't in your project root.  One easy way of doing that is to (1) add the parent of your project folder to `PYTHONPATH`, (2) change `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to `projectfoldername.settings`.

Comment: It seems to me that number two ahs already been done. In the shell, when I'm inside the project directory (the one that contains manage.py), if I type env I see DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings. After this if i run python manage.py [command] nothing is happening.

Comment: Is the mysite parent folder in your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: when i open a python session and run >import sys >sys.path the project folder is first in the returned list.

Comment: Yes, but it is the parent of the project folder that needs to be in that list (looks like it would be `/Users/davidhaddad/Desktop`). The reason is that manage.py tries to do the equivalent of an `import mysite.settings` and for that to succeed it needs to find `mysite` in `sys.path`.

Comment: turns out it's something completely unrelated. Overwrote my manage.py file by mistake. Using a new editor and must have inadvertently type something. thanks for the help bjorn. Shall I leave this up or delete the question at this point?

Comment: Glad you found a solution :-)  I don't know what common practice is on SO... I'd suggest leaving it unless someone more senior has an opinion.

Comment: Specifically, when using a GRAPHITE application, which commonly is installed in /opt/graphite and has a /opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/settings.py file, you need to have:  

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=graphite.settings